# jQuery autocomplete adding additional data with autocompleted data

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have an input field (text) that I want to perform autocomplete on with multiple names. It acts like the To: field in Gmail, with the user typing in a name and hitting enter and continuing. The problem is that I have a list of names and that's what gets added to the input field and once you submit, as far as I know, only the field string gets sent to the server. The problem is when there are two people with the same name, so: `John Smith, Bob, John Smith` might be inputted and that string will get sent to the server.

On the backend, all users have a unique id. Is there any way I can have the users' names be the autocomplete source but have their ids sent to the server?

I'm using jQuery 1.5.1 and this plugin: [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard search will offer up everything you need. You just need to use a `$.map()` function to get the data you need out from the server response. Example:

```
...
success: function (data) {
   response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
      return {
         id: item.ContactId,
         value: item.LastName + ", " + item.FirstName
      }
   }))
}
...
```

Then just store the selected items (including the ids and names) in a `$().data()` variable on the input. Example:

```
...
select: function (event, ui) {
   $(this).data("Selected", item);
}
...
```

Now when you're ready to post your value back to the server, you can simply send the id of the selected entry like so:

```
var idToSend = $("#autoComplete").data("Selected").id;
```

I hope that helps. Good luck!

*** * EDIT * ***

Sorry, the `$.map()` was a split thought. The `data.d` in my example is .NET specific, but there are two properties that are native to the Autocomplete plugin (`.value` and `.label`).

`.value` will be what is shown and stored if `.label` does not exist; otherwise, `.value` will be treated as the value stored in the input post-selection, and `.label` will be what is displayed in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Use the select event in Jquery UI autocomplete to trigger javascript that will store the IDs you need in a hidden field in the same form.  See the documentation for the select event here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select